# how to check in GIT if someone else has downloaded a certain branch

Tags: git

Is there a way to check to see if someone else has downloaded a branch (master or some other branch) in GIT?

Please advise.

Thanks,

Comment: It depends on how you serve git

Answer (score 1):

Here's the options as I see them:

- If you're serving files from the git-daemon, you could run it with
  the `--verbose --syslog` options to log what's been downloaded.
- For HTTP/HTTPS downloads one should be able to determine at minimum the specific data downloaded, and based on the request format probably the branch info also, one the web server access logs.
- I'm not 100% sure about the SSH protocol, but my guess is that due to
  its encrypted nature you won't see much. Actually if sshd is run with
  debug logging you might see some information. But you really shouldn't do that without cause, as (to quote the man page) `Logging with a DEBUG level violates the privacy of users and is not recommended.

If keeping detailed information on who has downloaded branches is critical to your situation, it appears at first blush using the first option would be best.

Also, [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html) may provide logging capability along with its advanced security features.